# Multi-Function Button

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to HTML design, and am trying to make a button that when click the first time, changes the text to 'Look, I did something!!!', and that works fine. Then, on the next press, I want to change it back to the original. I was able to successfully do that, but once it was done, it wasn't able to be done again. This was that design.

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("button_text").innerHTML = "Look I did something!!!";
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Go Back";
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("button_text").innerHTML = "Click Me. I'm a button!!!";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click Me";
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help me with this, as I really have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: Plz provide your HTML code.

Comment: Your first `.onclick` handler, when run, does what you want then gets _replaced_ by that inner `.onclick` handler, so the next click changes the text  back ... but then that handler stays in place so every click after that runs the handler but it just changes the text "back" again, to what it already says. You should keep track of the state outside the handler, as jacobcambell says in an answer, and not nest or replace the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to toggle a button's text:

```js
let active = false;

document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
  // "Toggle" the active variable, if false it becomes true, and vice-versa
  active = !active;
  
  // Render different button text based on whether active is true or false
  if(active){
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = 'Look I did something!!!';
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = 'Click me';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

This is obviously very customizable depending on your needs.